# modification of base class through "data defined overlays"

Tags: python

Not sure title is correct, but it's hard to ask a question about something when you don't know what to call it.

Imagine you have a class of something like

```
class Creature():
    def __init__( self ):
        self.str = 13
        self.dex = 10
        ...
```

This creature will be given other definitions that affect it.  In this case, imagine a creature object was given the race of Orc.  Orc would increase it's str by 2.  It could be possible for a creature to get multiple of these property modifying templates.

Is there a way to organize the code that would make this elegant, pythonic, easy to maintain, and possibly data driven?

Answer (score 2):

First, here's how you'd do it *without* making it data-driven:

```
class Orc(Creature):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.str += 2
        self.race = 'Orc'
```

---

But what if you wanted it to be data driven? Let's assume the data are just stored in a table that maps race names to dicts, which themselves map attribute names to bonuses. Like this:

```
races = {
    'Human': {},
    'Orc': {'str': +2, 'cha': -1},
    'Elf': {'str': -1, 'dex': +1, 'int': +1}
}
```

That may be stored in a JSON file, or a SQLite database, or anything you want; it doesn't have to be a `dict` literal embedded in your source code. I'm just doing it that way to keep the example simple.

We could programmatically create `Human`, `Orc`, and `Elf` subclasses from this, but there's probably no good reason for that. All we really need is a factory function that creates an instance of the race, and after that they all act the same. So:

```
def create_creature(race):
    bonuses = races.get(race, {})
    creature = Creature()
    for attr, bonus in bonuses.items():
        setattr(creature, attr, getattr(creature, attr) + bonus)
    creature.race = race
    return creature
```

---

The only tricky part here is that [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) line. The key is that we don't know the name of the attribute at the time we're writing the code, we only know it at runtime, but we still want to be able to get or set the value of that attribute. Normally you don't want to use `setattr` and `getattr`—but when you need to dynamically access attributes by name, that's exactly what they're there for.

However, it's worth noting that there's another alternative. How much of your code actually relies on them being attributes of the `Creature` class? Could they just be members of a dict?

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = {'str': 13, 
                      'dex': 10,
                      # ...
                     }
```

If so, then that ugly `setattr` line becomes a lot nicer:

```
creature.stats[attr] += bonus
```

On the other hand, some other code in your program might become uglier. Maybe instead of this:

```
if player.str + roll(20) > enemy.str + roll(20):
```

… you have to write:

```
if play.stats['str'] + roll(20) > enemy.stats['str'] + roll(20)
```

This tradeoff pretty much always comes up with data-driven objects: one part of your program wants to treat them like data, another part wants to treat them like objects, and you have to balance the two.

Comment: This was one of the ways I was familiar with.  Glad to see someone recommend it as it validates kind of what I was thinking.  I was expecting some sort of class inheritance scheme to be superior, but your example really makes a lot of sense.  Also, it allows me to apply more than race across a creature to create or modify properties.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @robbie: It's worth learning how multiple inheritance works for the static case in Python, before designing the dynamic case. For example, imagine you had an `ElfWizard` that's a subclass of both `Elf` and `Wizard`. If you use `super`, instead of explicitly calling the subclass, the `Creature.__init__` will get called exactly once, then each subclass's `__init__` will get its change to modify the values exact once—exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `Orc` inherits from `Creature` and increases its `str` by 2:

```
class Creature():
    def __init__( self ):
        self.str = 13
        self.dex = 10

class Orc(Creature):
    def __init__( self ):
        Creature.__init__( self )
        self.str += 2
```

Here is one class that would rule them all:

```
class Creature():
    d_str = {None:13, "Orc":15}
    d_dex = {None:10, "Orc":10}

    def __init__( self, race=None ):
        self.race = race
        self.str = self.d_str[race]
        self.dex = self.d_dex[race]
```

Comment: The class to rule them all is clever.  I suppose I could set a self.race and make this work pretty well.  Good suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: @robbie Good point.  I added a `self.race` to the sample code.

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling `Creature.__init__` directly. Use `super`. (If this is Python 2.x code, that also means use `class Creature(object):`, but you'd want to make that change anyway…) Otherwise, imagine how you'd define an `OrcBarbarian` that's both an `Orc` and a `Barbarian`.